# Google Cloud , Compute Engine I can't create Password

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm new here so please do not hate. I tried to create a VM in Compute Engine but no password shows up.

Like this print:

[image]

Comment: Hi Cakeman, I believe you need to contact Google customer support with your issue -- rather than random internet denizens.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about configuring Google Cloud, not programming.

Comment: Ian Kemp. I just need help. ._.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Console: cannot login to new WIndows VM instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715142/google-cloud-console-cannot-login-to-new-windows-vm-instance)

Answer (score 4):

There have been some changes to Windows images two days ago.

First of all, you need to create the Windows instance. Later, you can get the Windows username and password clicking on the new "Create or reset Windows password" button that appears in your instance details. The following picture shows you how it looks like:

[image: Set Windows password]

You can choose the username and Compute Engine will generate a random password for your username.

You can do it using the [Cloud SDK](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcloud.google.com%2Fsdk%2F&ei=VChxVYK8L4roUuXqgOgI&usg=AFQjCNGJ6NuXLC5eFVGtotHysFNTyoS5-Q&bvm=bv.95039771,d.bGQ) as well using the command:

```
gcloud beta compute reset-windows-password windows-instance --zone ZONE --project PROJECT_ID
```

If you forget the password you'll need to reset the password again.

You can find more information about these changes in the following links:

[Link1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gce-discussion/OXjzN3zATnw/AxiNEVSJcX4J)

[Link2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/release-notes#june032015)

[Link3](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows#understand_auth)

Once you have logged into the Windows instance, you can modify the password and use a custom password following the steps you can find [at the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows#set_a_custom_password).