# Google Cloud Console: cannot login to new WIndows VM instance

Tags: windows, authentication, passwords, google-compute-engine

I'm using the Google Cloud Console to create a new Windows VM. I've tried both Server 2008 and 2012. In either case I cannot log into the VM once it's up because it says I have an incorrect credentials.

I've read this article:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows#understand_auth

However, it doesn't seem clear to me how this works. Previously I simply copied the password during the create new instance process, and the username was the same as the GC project ID name. This time I tried the name approach (projectID name + password) using RDP and couldn't login. I then tried my own username + the copied password and it still doesn't work.

Again, I haven't lost a password. The instance is brand new, I copied the password from the setup process, and I'm still not able to connect via RDP. Is there another step that I'm missing? Or do I not have the correct username in place?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

We recently changed the way users log into new Windows instances. All the details should be at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows#log_into_a_windows_virtual_machine
but please let me walk you through the steps.

Once you created a new Windows instance in the Developers console, please go into the new instance details page: 
[image]

and then click "Create or reset Windows password".
[image]

You can now choose a local Windows username in the dialog [by default, this is your gmail without "@gmail.com"]
[image]

Click "Set" and wait until the new password is displayed to you.

Hope this helps.
--Alex

Comment: Alex: thanks for the quick reply. The solution you posted makes perfect sense. However, it reveals perhaps the real crux of the problem. When I log into Developer Console, view this particular VM, and then view the "Windows remote access" section I do **not** have the options that you show in your screen shot. I simply have the option for "Get the command to view username and password used to create the instance". There is no button for "Create or reset Windows password". My VM is in Zone A. Why would this option not be available to me?

Comment: Hi John, what browser are you using? You can see the button in Chrome and Safari only right now; [we are working on the IE and Firefox support](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows#known_issues). Alternatively, you can use [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/): gcloud beta compute reset-windows-password <INSTANCE>

Comment: Sorry! I was using FF. I switched to Chrome and it worked exactly as described. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered this issue on a PC that was working fine yesterday.  Ie yesterday I could reset the password, today I could not.  This was running on Chrome.  The issue was that you could click reset password, get to the dialog with the user, but selecting 'reset' just caused it to spin and spin.  I solved it by closing the browser and reopening it.  Or open in Firefox.  This was on a brand new VM instance.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex states, this is a browser issue. I was not able to see the "Create or reset Windows password" button using Firefox. I went into Chrome and followed his instructions, everything worked as expected and now I'm up and running via RDP.

Comment: By now the 'reset password' button should appear in Firefox and IE too.